# Recursive func Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog. Not really able to get how it works.

```
fillmap([HF|TF],[HG|TG],L,X,Y,Map1):-
   ...
   replace((EX,EY,none),Map1,(EX,EY,HF),Map2),
   ...
   (L1>0-> write("G0"),fillmap(TF,TG,L1,EX,EY,Map2);
   write("G=0")).
```

Map is a list. I am changing it in every recursive call and I can see it in the output by write func. But I want to get the changed Map where I am calling it. But I am not getting the updated Map there. How to get that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `find/3`? what is `replace/4`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are satisfied with the values for `Map2` that are computed by this predicate and printed out, and you just want to be able to "pass it back" or "return it" to a caller.

All passing of data between predicates in Prolog is done via predicate arguments. So you need an extra argument for the `fillmap` predicate:

```
fillmap([HF|TF], [HG|TG], L, X, Y, Map1, Map2):-
    ...   % your code exactly as before
```

When you call this predicate, pass in a fresh variable `NewMap` as the last argument, and after the call that variable will be bound to the new map.

Comment: I did try that earlier. But it wasn't working. Guess I am doing something wrong.

Comment: This is predicate                                                                          `  fillmap([HF|TF],[HG|TG],L,X,Y,Map1,Map3):-
   .....
   replace((EX,EY,none),Map1,(EX,EY,HF),Map2),
   ....
   (L1>0-> fillmap(TF,TG,L1,EX,EY,Map2,Map3);
   write("G=0")).'                                                                                                And I am calling the predicate in this  `                                                          fillmap(F,G,L,R,C,SX,SY,Map,NewS):-
 fillmap(F,G,L,SX,SY,Map,NMap),
 write("\nMap:"),
 write(NMap),
 NewS=[R,C,SX,SY,NMap]. `

Comment: @TeenuTTT make that `fillmap( [HF|TF],[HG|TG], L,X,Y, Map1,Map3):-  ... (L1>0 -> write("G0"), fillmap( TF,TG, L1,EX,EY, Map2,Map3);
   write("G=0"), Map3=Map2).`